# TypeError: form is undefined

Tags: jquery

Why do i get error -

```
TypeError: form is undefined[Learn More]
```

when i submit the form?

What do i need to change?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit_save-btn", function(e) {

  var element = $(this);

  var form = $(this).closest('form')[0];
  for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
    if (form.elements[i].type == 'file') {
      if (form.elements[i].value == '') {
        form.elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(form.elements[i]);
      }
    }
  }

var formData = new FormData(form);
var act = "edit";
formData.push({name: 'act', value: 'edit'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='#' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <tr id="4" class="fadeSec item">
    <td class="item_logo"><input name="file[]" type="file"></td>
    <td class="item_name"><input name="agnt[name]" value="Agency 2" type="text"><span>*</span></td>
    <td class="item_mainEmail"><input name="agnt[mainEmail]" value="email@gmail.com" type="text"></td>
    <td class="item_contact"><textarea type="text" name="agnt[contact]">some details</textarea></td>
    <td class="panel-menu">
      <div class="edit_msg"></div>

      <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw edit_form-loader"></i>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success edit_save-btn">Save</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

................
............. .................  ......................

Comment: Until now It's run only my local server...@Taplar

Comment: When i'm using INSPECT i see that the the code auto change - the FORM tags is open and directly close above the TR tag. not sure why it's happened :/ @Taplar

Comment: So, if i want to insert FORM inside a table, how can i do that ? @Taplar

Answer (score 1):

You issue may be stemming from the fact that you have invalid html.

```html
<form action='#' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <tr id="4" class="fadeSec item">
    <td class="item_logo"><input name="file[]" type="file"></td>
    <td class="item_name"><input name="agnt[name]" value="Agency 2" type="text"><span>*</span></td>
    <td class="item_mainEmail"><input name="agnt[mainEmail]" value="email@gmail.com" type="text"></td>
    <td class="item_contact"><textarea type="text" name="agnt[contact]">some details</textarea></td>
    <td class="panel-menu">
      <div class="edit_msg"></div>

      <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw edit_form-loader"></i>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success edit_save-btn">Save</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

`tr` elements are table rows.  HTML expects them to be children of a table or a table child's child.  They are not loose elements like others.  They must belong to a table.  So it may be the case that your browser is trying to "fix" your markup by closing the form before the table data.  So then when you try to do `$(this).closest('form')` it would not find the form, because the button is not a child of the form.  To fix this, try fixing your markup.

```html
<form action='#' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <table>
    <tr id="4" class="fadeSec item">
      <td class="item_logo"><input name="file[]" type="file"></td>
      <td class="item_name"><input name="agnt[name]" value="Agency 2" type="text"><span>*</span></td>
      <td class="item_mainEmail"><input name="agnt[mainEmail]" value="email@gmail.com" type="text"></td>
      <td class="item_contact"><textarea type="text" name="agnt[contact]">some details</textarea></td>
      <td class="panel-menu">
        <div class="edit_msg"></div>

        <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw edit_form-loader"></i>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success edit_save-btn">Save</a>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Put the tr in a table.

Also, rather than going up to the form, you could try going to the table row and find the input elements off of that element, rather than the form.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit_save-btn", function(e) {
  //go from the button, up to the row, then find the children file inputs
  $(this).closest('tr').find('[type=file]').each(function(index, fileInput){
    //remove the file input if it does not have a value set
    if (fileInput.value == '') $(fileInput).remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: I can't. each row should be editable. that's means that each row should be a form...

Comment: In that case, why not do `closest('tr')` rather than the form, since each of your table rows are going to contain all your unique groupings, no?  Otherwise you could try putting the form around the tr, but the table around the form and see if it works.

Comment: I'm not sure if i can use just tr. i need to submit form, for each row, that contain file field. will it works without FORM tag?

Comment: I'm not saying remove the form tag.  I'm just saying try to go up to the tr in your logic, rather than the form, and find the input element as a child of that tr.

Comment: like this - `var form = $(this).closest('tr'); ` ?

Comment: @Roi checkout the edit I made to the answer.  I included a proposal at the bottom.

Comment: I'm checking it right now. but file field is only one of the type i have. each form include 2 text fielld, 1 file field and 1 textarea field. i think your code refer only to the file field....

Comment: Yep, as that's what you are doing in your original code (`form.elements[i].type == 'file'`)

Comment: can you please help me with that code? please see my first post. how do i get `formData` with all the form field?

Comment: Uh, if you have a different question than what your question originally started as, then that needs to be another SO question.  Otherwise, this question is subject to scope creep, and it's going to be very hard for anyone to answer your question as the question is changing.

Comment: it's actually the same - because i'm trying to get all the form fields and my browser send my an error...

Comment: Your original question was why the form element was undefined.  The new question is how to use the form element.  Those are different questions.